# How can I find the current screen scale of my CarPlay screen?

Tags: swift, objective-c, carplay

How can I find the current screen scale of my CarPlay screen?

I'm interested in how to understand the current scale for the screen. In a lot of cases it is 2, but on high resolution screens it turns on scale 3. We need to understand what specific scale is currently used in the application

Comment: I don't use CarPlay, but I guess it's the same logic as for iDevices: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617836-scale Apple called them "Retina", but the logic is how do you divide a "point": is it 1 px, 4, 9, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpinterfacecontroller/3578118-cartraitcollection

Other than that, I don't think it's possible to read the actual screen size/resolution of the display